# Convert a php array to js array with dynamic size of array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, yii2, google-visualization

I'm using google chart to draw a chart for my Yii2 website. I have php array with below format:

```
<?php var_dump($a_tg_dat_san_con); ?>
==> Result
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(0) } }
```

Then, Because of building dataTable for Google Chart, I have to convert above array to Js array like this:

```
data_row = [
                [<?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con[0][0])?>, <?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con[0][1])?>],
                [<?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con[1][0])?>, <?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con[1][1])?>],
                [<?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con[2][0])?>, <?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con[2][1])?>],
            ];
```

The problem is the php array is a dynamic array.
How can I do a convert for all cases of array?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the whole array to the javasript variable

```
var data_row = <?=json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con);?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I though too much.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode supports multidimensional arrays. No need to split everything up and build your own json.

```
json_encode($a_tg_dat_san_con);
```

Will give you what you are trying to hand build, and it doesn't care how  many rows you have.